# Azure CosmosDB SQL APi how to save date created when i create a document

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to Azure CosmosDB using SQL API. I am developing an ASP.Net core api to create a simple customer. I want to store the date created. How to do this? i have the property _ts which keeps updating when the customer entity is updated. But i want to store date created.

```
 public abstract class BaseCosmosEntity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("_ts")]
        public string ts { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("_type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone help how to store DateCreated in Azure cosmosdb?

Thanks

Comment: Just add a date property that you use for date created.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the .NET SDK, you can use a `DateTime` property which will serialize as ISO 8601 format. I use this in my entity class:

```
public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
```

Be sure to set this within your creation operation.